# How do I create a set from a multi-line string in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have a multiline string as input. For example: `my $input="a\nb\nc\nd"`

I would like to create a set from this input, so that I can determine whether elements from a vector of strings are present in the set. My question is, how do I create a set from a multi-line string in Perl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) can be used to store lines into an array variable:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $input = "a\nb\nc\nd";
my @lines = split /\n/, $input;

print Dumper(\@lines);

__END__

$VAR1 = [
          'a',
          'b',
          'c',
          'd'
        ];
```

Answer (score 0):

@toolic is right; [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) does the trick to grab the input.

But you might want to go a step further and put those values into a hash, if you want to check set membership later on.  Something like this:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $input = "a\nb\nc\nd";
my @lines = split /\n/, $input;

my %set_contains;

# set a flag for each line in the set
for my $line (@lines) {
    $set_contains{ $line } = 1;
}
```

Then you can quickly check set membership like this:

```
if ( $set_contains{ $my_value } ) {
    do_something( $my_value );
}
```

Comment: perl doesn't have a native set type, so hashes usually fill that role, so IMO this is exactly what is being asked for, not "a step further"